# Orchard CMS won't play nice with PayPal IPN + GA?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, orchardcms, paypal-ipn, orchardcms-1.10

This question has one main goal; to bring in Response data from an HTTP POST sent by PayPal into GA.

Validating the IPN has not been the issue; all PayPal data is successfully received. 
The Issue lies in trying to send the data to GA; there is something not communicating and no data is sent.

I believe it is a scope issue with the  `ga` javascript object somehow not firing correctly.

Currently I have a `<script = 'text/javascript'>` tag that exists in the source code of a Content (Page)

This code listens for and validates the IPN POST as `response`.

`if (response == 'VERIFIED') {...`
I store what should be the price in `var x = e.parameter.mc_gross`
Then after everything is matched I run, 
`ga(function () {
  ga('set', 'metric3', x);
});`

I have combed through this documentation and it is miserable trying to find a solution. I am now trying to open the website file in VS to see if I can create a custom module to solve this issue but even finding where to download the site or how to upload a module is increasingly frustrating.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate anyone taking time to answer, especially now.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting the custom javascript on the Page content item and where did you include analytics? Where is your website hosted? Complex scenarios like this usually require a custom module, but you shouldn't need to upload it to gallery. You can simply add custom modules to your solution and use them as is.

Comment: The custom javascript is inside the body of the Page content item. The analytics is integrated through GTM as a universal tag on all pages. << I can see this being the issue. As it fires on page view >> The hosting shouldn't be the issue? The only thing is that I haven't found it simple to add a module, I see featured and a gallery some modules that I think would help like 'C# Scripting' are enabled but how do I use them? I'm sorry if this is obvious; I'm coming from 'React' and this is all brand new.

Comment: Writing javascript on a page's layout doesn't seem like a great idea, since you have no control over dependencies, order of execution etc. I would forget about trying to implement this with the basic building blocks. The reason I ask about hosting is because it's very simple to add custom features IF you are building the source and yourself and have access to the files. Just create a custom module and set up a classic MVC controller with a view that includes all of your scripts. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/ to get started.